# React Query: How to properly show a loading state in disabled query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

What I want is to show a **loading spinner** only when the query is **enabled**, if I try to use the `isLoading` flag with the query disabled, this shows me the spinner having into account that there is no data yet in the cache.

so the question is: **how do I show the loading state only when the query is enabled?** if the query is disabled it should not be shown.

### Reference code

```js
export const useGetCustomerProfile = (customerId) => {
  const request = createClient({
    url: `/customers/${customerId}/trusted-profile`,
  });

  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ['trusted-profile', customerId],
    queryFn: request,
    enabled: !!customerId,
  });
};

// this will show the spinner by default because there is no data in the cache
// the first time, the spinner should be only shown when `someId`
// will be different than `null || undefined`
const { isLoading } = useGetCustomerProfile(someId);
```

PD: I’m using react-query v4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in v4, you can use the `isInitialLoading` flag for disabled queries. This is documented here:

https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/disabling-queries#isinitialloading

**update for v5**

in v5, you can now use `isLoading` with disabled queries, because `isLoading` is the same as `isInitialLoading`. the old `isLoading` was renamed to `isPending`

Comment: useQuery does not seem to expose 'isInitialLoading' anymore (although the docs also still state otherwise). I think we should use 'isIdle'.

Comment: I think you have the wrong version

Comment: You are correct, it seems that I'm on 3.39.3 :/
Ah...it seems that the package is now "@tanstack/react-query"

Comment: I see 'isInitialLoading' is deprecated in v5 though...

Comment: in v5, we've renamed `isLoading` to `isPending`, so `isInitialLoading` is now just `isLoading` :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to check `isIdle` which will be true when enabled is false and no data is available.

e.g.

```js
const {
   isIdle, 
   isLoading, 
   isError, 
   data, 
   error  
} = useGetCustomerProfile(someId);

  if(isIdle) return <NoDataInterface />;
  if(isLoading) return <LoadingSpinner />;
  if(isError) return <ErrorInterface error={error} />

  return <InterfaceWithData data={data} />;
```

Comment: What is I just want to use the `isLoading` state? I need to validate `isIdle` and `isLoading`? something like `const isLoadingCustomer = fetchStatus !== 'idle' && isLoding`?

Comment: I think the accepted answer is this: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/disabling-queries#isinitialloading

although `idle` can be used, it is less intuitive, and React Query gives us an easier way to validate this with `isInitialLoading`